# Define a self kwarg argument within a FORM request

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Here is what I am trying to solve.
In my app I invite users to join a team. So I created a form that ask only for a mail, generate a random password, create a user and then send a mail to the user.
The user go to the mail and finish his registration by providing first name last name and update his password and is finally part of the team.

I gave it a try, but my code was bad :

```
def ApplicantRegister2(request, pk1=None):
    InviteFormSet = formset_factory(ApplicantForm2)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = InviteFormSet(request.POST)

        if(formset.is_valid()):
            for i in formset:
                mail = i.cleaned_data['Email']
                user = MyUser(email = mail)
                password = MyUser.objects.make_random_password()
                user.set_password(password)
                user.is_active = False
                user.is_candidate = True
                user.save()
                u1 = user.id #get user id
                a1 = MyUser.objects.get(email = request.user.email) #get HRuser email
                a2 = Project.objects.filter(project_hr_admin = a1)  #get all project created by the HRuser
                a3 = a2.latest('id') # extract the last project
                a4 = a3.team_id # extract the team linked to the project
                a4.applicant.add(u1) # add the member to the team

                current_site = get_current_site(request)
                message = render_to_string('acc_active_email.html', {
                    'user':user,
                    'domain':current_site.domain,
                    'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                    'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
                    })
                mail_subject = 'You have been invited to SoftScores.com please sign in to get access to the app'
                to_email = user.email
                email = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, to=[to_email])
                    email.send()
            messages.success(request, 'testouille la fripouille')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('website:ProjectDetails', kwargs={'pk1':a3.id}))
        else:
            print("The entered form is not valid")

    else:
        formset = InviteFormSet()
    return render(request,'applicant_register.html', {'formset':formset})
```

I do not like the fact that I extract the last project created so I added in my URL the project in question and now http://127.0.0.1:8000/registration/project/59/auth_team_register3/
with 59 beeign the project ID the kwarg.

I would like to use it instead of a3 = a2.latest('id') but providing self.kwargs['pk1'] give me the errors or that self is not define or that Reverse for 'applicant_register3' with keyword arguments '{'pk1': ''}' not found.

## edited code :

```
 def applicantregister2(request, pk1):

    InviteFormSet = formset_factory(ApplicantForm2)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = InviteFormSet(request.POST)

        if(formset.is_valid()):

            for i in formset:
                mail = i.cleaned_data['Email']
                if MyUser.objects.filter(email = mail).exists():
                    user = MyUser.objects.get(email=mail)
                    u1 = user.id # get user ID
                    a2 = Project.objects.get(id = 'pk1')
                    a2.applicant.add(u1)

                    invited_user = MyUser.objects.get(email = mail)
                    current_site = get_current_site(request)
                    message = render_to_string('acc_join_email.html', {
                        'user': invited_user.first_name,
                        'domain':current_site.domain,
                        })
                    mail_subject = 'You have been invited to SoftScores.com please LogIn to get access to the app'
                    to_email = mail
                    email = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, to=[to_email])
                    email.send()
                else:
                    user = MyUser(email = mail)
                    password = MyUser.objects.make_random_password()
                    user.set_password(password)
                    user.is_active = False
                    user.is_candidate = True
                    user.save()
                    u1 = user.id #get user id
                    a2 = Project.objects.get(id = 'pk1')

                    a2.applicant.add(u1)
                    current_site = get_current_site(request)
                    message = render_to_string('acc_active_email.html', {
                    'user':user,
                    'domain':current_site.domain,
                    'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                    'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
                    })
                    mail_subject = 'You have been invited to SoftScores.com please sign in to get access to the app'
                    to_email = user.email
                    email = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, to=[to_email])
                    email.send()
            messages.success(request, 'testouille la fripouille')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('website:ProjectDetails', kwargs='pk1'))
        else:
            print("The entered form is not valid")

    else:
        formset = InviteFormSet()
    return render(request,'applicant_register.html', {'formset':formset})
```

HTML Code :

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block body %}
<div class="container paddingtop80 marginbottom30">
  <div class="jumbotron greenback">
      Test
      <a href="{% url 'registration:applicant_register3' pk1=project.id %}" class="btn btn-success" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>   Add Applicants</a>
  </div>
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

view:

```
class RecruitmentPage(generic.ListView):
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    template_name = "recruitment_index.html"
    model = Project ## may need to be changed

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return get_object_or_404(Project, id=self.kwargs['pk1'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a function based view

```
def ApplicantRegister2(request, pk1=None):
    ...
```

Therefore `self.kwargs['pk1']` won't work. There is no `self`. Just use `pk1`. Note you have `pk1=None`, so perhaps you need to check that it is not `None` before you use it. That depends on your URLs.

I highly recommend that you name you use `underscore_case` for your function based views.

```
def applicant_register2(request, pk1=None):
```

At the moment, `ApplicantRegister2` looks like a class, which will be confusing to any other Python developers that look at your code or Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: So if there is no self how can I extract the project that is in my URL ?

Comment: As I said, **just use pk1**. It's there in your function signature `(request, pk1=None)`.

Comment: Yes but now the pk1 = None and not the my project ID. I used that because previously 'pk1':a3.id and without I got a Got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk1' issue. I do not want to use pk1':a3.id because it extract the last project and not the current project..

Comment: that is my URL: url(r'^project/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/auth_applicant_register3/$', views.ApplicantRegister2, name='applicant_register3'),

Comment: that is my URL: url(r'^project/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/auth_applicant_register3/$', views.ApplicantRegister2, name='applicant_register3'),

Comment: With that URL pattern, `pk1` will be `'59'` when you go to `/registration/project/59/auth_team_register3/`. Unless you are using the view for another URL pattern, you can remove the `None` default: `def ApplicantRegister2(request, pk1):`

Comment: I do not use that for for another url but I still get the same error : django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'applicant_register3' with keyword arguments '{'pk1': ''}' not
 found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['registration/project/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/auth_applicant_register3/$'] Can it come from the HTML ? but the error is on the reverse .. so ..

Comment: I added the view in the post: I should be able to access 'registration:applicant_register3' pk1=project.id since I used the get_object no ?

Comment: `{'pk1': ''}` means that the variable is missing from your template context. That's a separate issue, I can't help with that here.

Comment: I created a new question with my real issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162985/discussion-between-ben2pop-and-alasdair).